# Understanding hexadecimal data format in BluetoothLE write characteristic (Windows UWP Sample app)

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth

I've set up a UWP sample BluetoothLE server using the code provided [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BluetoothLE/cs/Scenario3_ServerForeground.xaml.cs). I'm using [LightBlue](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/lightblue/id557428110#?platform=iphone) on my iPhone as a client to read/write data to the characteristics exposed by the server.

Here's a description of the service:

> This scenario allows the system to publish a calculator service. Remote
> clients (including this sample on another machine) can supply 2
> operands and an operator and get a result.
>
> Valid range for Operand is integer values. Valid range for Operator is
> 1-4 corresponding to +,-,*,/ respectively.

So there are 3 write characteristics, and 1 read characteristic. Using LightBlue on my iPhone, I write data to the operand characteristics in hexadecimal format, however I'm a little confused.

I expected to write the hexadecimal representation of a 32 unsigned integer, eg:

```
(hex) 00000001 = (binary) 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 = (decimal) 1
```

However this is interpreted by the server as decimal 16777216. After experimenting, I determined

```
(hex) 01000000 = (decimal) 1.
```

My assumptions are obviously faulty about the hexadecimal data format.

I believe this is the method in the server script responsible for receiving the request from the client, the full class is available [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BluetoothLE/cs/Scenario3_ServerForeground.xaml.cs).

```
/// <param name="request"></param>
/// <param name="opCode">Operand (1 or 2) and Operator (3)</param>
private void ProcessWriteCharacteristic(GattWriteRequest request, CalculatorCharacteristics opCode)
{
    if (request.Value.Length != 4)
    {
        // Input is the wrong length. Respond with a protocol error if requested.
        if (request.Option == GattWriteOption.WriteWithResponse)
        {
            request.RespondWithProtocolError(GattProtocolError.InvalidAttributeValueLength);
        }
        return;
    }

    var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(request.Value);
    reader.ByteOrder = ByteOrder.LittleEndian;
    int val = reader.ReadInt32();

    switch (opCode)
    {
        case CalculatorCharacteristics.Operand1:
           operand1Received = val;
           break;
        case CalculatorCharacteristics.Operand2:
           operand2Received = val;
           break;
        case CalculatorCharacteristics.Operator:
           if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(CalculatorOperators), val))
           {
                if (request.Option == GattWriteOption.WriteWithResponse)
                {
                    request.RespondWithProtocolError(GattProtocolError.InvalidPdu);
                }
                return;
           }
           operatorReceived = (CalculatorOperators)val;
           break;
    }
    // Complete the request if needed
    if (request.Option == GattWriteOption.WriteWithResponse)
    {
        request.Respond();
    }

    UpdateUX();
}
```

Can anyone explain what I'm missing? Coming at this from a mainly frontend web development background; data types are not my strong suit!

Comment: You should pay your attention to this line `reader.ByteOrder = ByteOrder.LittleEndian;` you have to pass bytes in order from lowest to highest.

Comment: That explains everything! I’ll try it again, taking this into consideration, and will let you know the result. Any thoughts on why this conversion is necessary?

Comment: What you are seeing is Intel format that is the way the microprocessor stores the bytes.  Whan you do addtion there is a caryout/carryin so it is faster to send least significant bytes first. So where the byte order of a 32 bit interger is 3,2,1,0  the order you would normally see is 0,1, 2, 3

Comment: @NickDawes I don't know why this is done, but if you can change this code you better switch it to `BigEndian` to feel comfortable.

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev switching from LittleEndian to BigEndian gave me the result I expected, thanks! I learnt something today. If you answer the question with your suggestion I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change this line

```
reader.ByteOrder = ByteOrder.LittleEndian;
```

to this

```
reader.ByteOrder = ByteOrder.BigEndian;
```

or invert order of bytes in hexadecimal string you pass to service.